# API method for swapping characters inside a string in Java

Tags: java, string

Is there a native method in Java to do character swapping inside `Strings`. I mean, I need to write a function like this everytime and its pretty boring:

---

```
    public static String modifyString(String str,int x,int y){

    char arr[]=str.toCharArray();
    char t= arr[x];
    arr[x]=arr[y];
    arr[y]=t;

    String s= new String(arr);
    return s;

}
```

---

Comment: Not a native way but some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956199/how-to-swap-string-characters-in-java

Comment: native is probably not that best word to use since it has its own meaning in Java.

Comment: on an unrelated note, you can improve performance by using `arr[x]^=arr[y]; arr[y]^=arr[x]; arr[x]^=arr[y];`

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob is that really faster than simple assignments?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to create a temp variable and they are both three commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class does not contain a method for swapping characters. Unfortunately, you'll either need to roll your own, or look into using a third party library.