# iterate through a string swap first and last char

Tags: java

I need a user to enter a word and the code to swap the first and last char in the string e.g. 'hello' should output 'oellh'

```
public void compute(){
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){

            if (name.length() > 2 ) {

            }
            else {
                strBuff.append(name.charAt(i));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap String characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956199/how-to-swap-string-characters-in-java)

Comment: Yes this is part of a problem I have for homework

Comment: I have tried to implement the above solution and can not get it to work